# "off-topic" versus "insufficient research"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting
> answers.
>
> Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research &
> understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a)
> clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it
> or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either
> case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

"Off-topic" is a valid reason for closing.

"Lack of research" is also a valid reason.

But, "lack of research" and "off-topic" are two completely different things, are they not?  Neither one implies the other.

Comment: All the questions are closed because off-topic, which just means the question should not have been asked on the site. It's not that either a question is off-topic or the question lacks of research.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the Community-specific close reasons. All of these lumped under off topic due to how the templates are coded.

We can not change the top portion, only the wording of the bottom portion.

Comment: Hmmm.  That sounds like a S.E. design error.

Comment: It’s very intentional. You could make a case to change it on meta SE as sites all use common code base.

Comment: Intentional, to call it "community-specific" in the flag menu but change that to "off-topic" in the label?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic

Comment: @WGroleau All the closing reasons are for off-topic questions, which means we close questions that we consider off-topic.

Comment: @WGroleau "*design error*".
Not quite. SE is notorious for its learning curve, especially for a requirement of arcane knowledge.
One instance of this is the use of double-speak, where a word or phrase has a meaning that is significantly different from its obvious English meaning. In this case, while "off-topic" *would* apply to a question about Windows Registry in this Apple group, that isn't  what the term actually means. SE uses it to mean that the question doesn't meet the minimum requirements for questions on this site. Once one's brain can appropriately double-think, it all makes sense.

Comment: And _that_ sounds like "security by obfuscation."  :-)